# Mapping @ManyToOne / Foreign Key Hibernate Java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, foreign-keys, mapping

First of all, sorry if the subject has already been answered, but i've been searching for almost 6hours in a row, and trying everything i could find on the web, but i'm still stuck..

I Have a problem when i'm executing my code.. I can't find the origin of it, nor a solution...

Here's my different classes: (btw it's my first post on SOF, let me know if you need more information).

I'm going to post my Pojo's, useful DAO's and MySQL table creation orders, and the error message i get.

POJOs:

-Celebrite:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Celebrite")
public class Celebrite implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="numCelebrite")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@JoinColumn(name="numCelebrite")
private int numCelebrite;

@Column(name="nom")
private String nom;

@Column(name="prenom")
private String prenom;

@Column(name="nationalite")
private String nationalite;

@Column(name="epoque")
private String epoque;

public Celebrite() {
    super();
}

public Celebrite(String nom, String prenom, String nationalite, String epoque) {
    super();
    this.nom = nom;
    this.prenom = prenom;
    this.nationalite = nationalite;
    this.epoque = epoque;
}


public int getNumCelebrite() {
    return numCelebrite;
}

public void setNumCelebrite(int numCelebrite) {
    this.numCelebrite = numCelebrite;
}
//Other getters/setters
}
```

-Monument

```
@Entity
public class Monument implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String codeM;
    private String nomM;
    private String proprietaire;
    private String typeMonument;
    private float latitude;
    private float longitude;

    public Monument() {
        super();
    }
    public Monument( String codeM,String nomM, String propritaire, String typeMonument, float latitude, float longitude) {
        super();
        this.codeM=codeM;
        this.nomM = nomM;
        this.proprietaire = propritaire;
        this.typeMonument = typeMonument;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public Monument( String nomM, String propritaire, String typeMonument, float latitude, float longitude) {
        super();

        this.nomM = nomM;
        this.proprietaire = propritaire;
        this.typeMonument = typeMonument;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getCodeM() {
        return codeM;
    }

    public void setCodeM(String codeM) {
        this.codeM = codeM;
    }

    //other getters/setters..
}
```

-AssocieA (translation : AssociatedTo)

```
@Entity
public class AssocieA  implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     @Id
     @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinColumn(name="numCelebrite",referencedColumnName="numCelebrite")
     private Celebrite celebrite;
     //private int numCelebrite;

     @Id
     @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinColumn(name="codeM",referencedColumnName="codeM")
    //private String codeM;
     private Monument monument;

    public AssocieA() {
    }

        public AssocieA(Celebrite celebrite, Monument monument) {
        super();
        this.celebrite = celebrite;
        this.monument = monument;
    }

//getters/setters
}
```

Ok now the DAO, i'm only posting AssocieA's DAO as the others are working perfectly

```
public class DAOAssocieA {
    EntityManagerFactory emf;
    EntityManager em ;

    public DAOAssocieA() {
        super();
        this.emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpa-societe-pu");
        this.em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public List<AssocieA> getAssociatedMonuments(int numCelebrite){
        Query req=em.createQuery("Select a from AssocieA a where a.numCelebrite =" + numCelebrite);
        return  req.getResultList();
    }

    public List<AssocieA> getAssociatedCelebrities(String codeM){
        Query req=em.createQuery("Select a from AssocieA a where a.codeM = '"+codeM+"'");
        return req.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Finally, the 'main' class

```
public String execute() {
        setDAOc(new DAOCelebrite());
        setDAOm(new DAOMonument());
        setDAOa(new DAOAssocieA());
        if (getNom()==null)
            setNom("");
        if (getPrenom() == null)
            setPrenom("");
        if (getNationalite() == null)
            setNationalite("");
        if (getEpoque()==null)
            setEpoque(""); 
        setListeCelebrite(DAOc.getCelebritiesBy(getNom(),getPrenom(),getNationalite(), getEpoque()));
        System.out.println(getAssociated());
        if (getAssociated().equals("on")) {
            for (Celebrite c:listeCelebrite) {
                for (AssocieA a : DAOa.getAssociatedMonuments(c.getNumCelebrite())){
                    System.out.println(a.getCelebrite());
                    System.out.println(a.getMonument());
                }  
            }
        }  

        return ("success");
```

-> The return ("success") is because i use Struts2

Now, Table creation orders (on MySQL)

```
CREATE TABLE Celebrite (numCelebrite int auto_increment, nom varchar(16), prenom varchar(16), nationalite varchar(10), epoque varchar(6), PRIMARY KEY (numCelebrite)) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Monument (codeM varchar(5), nomM varchar(25), proprietaire varchar(10), typeMonument varchar(16), longitude float, latitude float, PRIMARY KEY (codeM)) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE AssocieA (codeM varchar(5), numCelebrite int, PRIMARY KEY (codeM,numCelebrite), FOREIGN KEY (codeM) REFERENCES Monument(codeM), FOREIGN KEY (numCelebrite) REFERENCES Celebrite(numCelebrite)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

To finish, the error message i get:

```
 org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: numCelebrite of: pojo.AssocieA [Select a from pojo.AssocieA a where a.numCelebrite =1]
```

I understand that the class 'AssocieA' doesn't have a "numCelebrite" property, but i thought that because of the @ManyToOne annotation, Celebrite Table should be loaded when Associe is loaded.

Else, could you give me some tips to explain how to do that?
The final goal is: having a Celebrite, i'd like, using the numCelebrite, to retrieve every Monuments related to it, using the AssocieA table.

Thank you in advance

EDIT: Solution found on another website by kulturman:
I was using native queries:

```
em.createQuery("from AssocieA a where a.numCelebrite  =" + numCelebrite);
```

Instead of JPQL (HQL queries):

```
em.createQuery("from AssocieA a where a.celebrite.numCelebrite  =" + numCelebrite);
```

For those who want to see directly the solution, it's in french on OpenClassRoom

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `@JoinColumn(name="numCelebrite")` and `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` in celebrity pojo, change `CascadeType.ALL` to `CascadeType.Persist` and let us know what happen. I'm not an expert but I think that way you can do the trick.

Comment: Welp i'm sorry, it didn't change anything :/

Comment: @Nox can you post your database structure? and is it any other error? perhaps you should post some other lines from the stacktrace.

Comment: Hey. Thank you for you help. I edited my first post as someone found the answer to my problem on another forum. Maybe i should've made this more obvious..
Apart from that, i'd like to thank you very much for taking the time to help people!

Comment: @Nox You're welcome! we are here to learn and help, can you give me the link to the other post to see the solution, so I can learn too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: looking at my previous edit, i obviously forgot to put the link at the end of my post.. i'm very sorry for this mistake. I'll create a reply to my post to make the answer clear

Answer (score 0):

Solution found on another website by kulturman:

I had to replace:

```
em.createQuery("from AssocieA a where a.numCelebrite  =" + numCelebrite);
Instead of JPQL (HQL queries):
```

by:

```
em.createQuery("from AssocieA a where a.celebrite.numCelebrite  =" + numCelebrite);
```

Here's the explanation:

I was building my query as if i was requesting my database :
The table AssocieA has the attribute "numCelebrite"

But in my case, I mapped the tables to my classes: Each row of the AssocieA table is now an instance of my AssocieA class.
Using a HQL query, i'm requesting on the instance of my class, not the table of my database.
So what i have to do is a.getCelebrite().getNumCelebrite(), hence the "a.celebrite.numCelebrite"

I hope i've made myself clear enough because my english is not that good.

Here's the link of the forum i had this answer on (it's in french):
https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/org-hibernate-queryexception?page=1#message-92165885